# is this sound [ɾ] or [ɹ]?

Tags: ipa, transcription

[Here](https://voca.ro/1g3yGasYmmJP)

my native language is claimed to have alveolar tap or trill as its rhotic sound but recently I've wondering if it's actually a plain alveolar approximant [ɹ] instead since I noticed that my [ɾ] sounds a lot more "weaker" than the [ɾ] sounds in languages like Spanish for example which seem to have a more pronounced and stronger [ɾ] sound

I have a hard time distinguishing between plain (unlabialized) [ɹ] and [ɾ] which why I am asking this question, I wonder if my /ɾ/ is actually [ɹ].

TLDR: is the rhotic sound in the recording [ɾ] or [ɹ].

Comment: This should be obvious by seeing if you can sustain it. You can make a long, sustained [ɹ] but not [ɾ].

Comment: That sounds like neither [ɾ] nor [ɹ] to me. It’s definitely not a tap, because you can here there’s clear frication and it’s sustained too long to be a tap (though not quite as long as a stereotypical approximant), but there’s also stronger frication than an approximant gives, so it’s not that either. It sounds to me like a very short [ɹ̝], a constricted [ɹ]. Your realisation is a common allophone of /ɾ/ in many languages – I can’t think of any examples where it’s a common allophone of /ɹ/, so there’s a good chance that your language would generally be considered to have /ɾ/ phonemically.

Comment: I guess it's [ɾ] since when I tried to sustain it it came out either as a short trill or some strange [ʒ]-like sound.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually my Language is generally considered to have trill /r/ Phonemically, though most of the time it isn't pronouced as such,  except when emphasizing a word or when speaking really fast, I'm a native speaker of Georgian.